# Go: How to Synchronize and Share Data

Tags: go

I'm writing a net/http server. My request handlers need access to some shared data that is updated by another go-routine. This go-routine keeps a single struct updated, and all of the net/http handlers need access to the same struct.

```
type MyData struct {
  Expiration time.Time
  A  string
  B  string
  C string
}

func update(data MyData) {
  go func() {
    for {
      if data.Expiration >= time.Now() {
        // set A, B, C
      }
      // sleep
    }
  }()
}
```

What's the best way to make a single, common MyData available to other go-routines? I was thinking a channel, but every reader of the channel should get the same MyData. The problem is that reading from a channel pops the item off the channel. I guess I'm looking for how to Peek() on the reader side, and Drain() on the writer side when it's time to update.

Comment: When you want "mutual exclusion" around a single resource, you usually want a ["mutex"](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex)

Comment: No nonobvious way--if it's updated frequently you want a Mutex or RWLock (if allowing multiple simultaneous readers is important). If it's read far, far more often than it's updated (like config that's used every request + rarely updated) you could have a pointer in an atomic.Value and replace it with a new instance when you refresh.

Comment: @twotwotwo: Thanks. That's what I figured. Let's say I make a MY_DATA global variable for my struct. Can I put the RWLock in the struct safely, or does the mutex need to be a separate global variable?

Comment: Marcel's got it--yes, mutexes and such can and often do live in the structs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutex based solution

```
type MyData struct {
    Expiration time.Time
    A  string
    B  string
    C string
}

type MutexedMyData struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    MyData MyData
}

var m = &MutexedMyData{}


func (m *MutexedMyData) Update(my_data MyData)  {
    m.Lock()
    m.MyData = my_data
    m.Unlock()
}

func (m *MutexedMyData) Read() MyData {
    u.RLock()
    value := m.MyData
    u.RUnlock()

    return value
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick newbie question: What's the significance of the `(m *MutexedMyData)` in the func declaration?

Comment: [methods on struct](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.ru/2011/06/methods-on-structs.html),  you can use them as m.Update or m.Read